# Цикл Pyqt5 (PySide 2)

Tags: python, pyqt5, таймер, pyside2

Цикл просто не работает, но мне надо чтобы оно каждую  секунду проверяло, равна ли переменная `time2`, переменной `time`.

По идеи это программа должна выключать комп тогда, когда укажет пользователь, но для теста оно просто должно выводить `2`.

[image: Наступает время, но ничего не происходит]

**Код 1:**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'vol.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(349, 333))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(349, 333))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 210, 121, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 351, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(7)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Время"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запуск"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*Внимание, писать время только в формате чч:мм:сс."))
```

**Код 2:**

```py
#import`s
import sys
import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from volu import Ui_MainWindow

#nothing
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

#nums
time = ui.lineEdit.text()
#def`s
def btn():
    x = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    x = x.split()
    x = x[1]
    x = x.split('.')
    time2 = x[0]
    while v == time:
        if str(v) == time:
            print("2")
            #os.system('shutdown /s /t 01')

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(btn)

#too nothing
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: qtimer/threading+pyqtSignal/qthread+pyqtSignal, и возможно qobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я не проверял ваш алгоритм, но правильно делать так:

```
import sys
# import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from volu import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(349, 333))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(349, 333))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 210, 121, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
# ?        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
# ?        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 351, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(7)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
# ?        self.label_2.setFont(font)
# ?        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Время"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запуск"))
# ?        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*Внимание, писать время только в формате чч:мм:сс."))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_btn)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите время в формате ЧЧ:ММ:СС')
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerHit)

    def timerHit(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString()
        time = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(time, current_time)
        if time == current_time:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'ВНИМАНИЕ', 
                'Пришло время, делайте что-нибудь!') 
        
    def on_btn(self):
        self.timer.start()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь таймером [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

#def`s
# По клику на кнопке запускаем/останавливаем таймер
def btn():
   # Если таймер не запущен то,
   if not timer.isActive():
       # Запустить таймер с интервалом 1 сек
       timer.start(1000)
   else:
       timer.stop();

# слот для таймера
def timeout():
    x = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    x = x.split()
    x = x[1]
    x = x.split('.')
    time2 = x[0]
    # цикл while не нужен!
    # вероятно v из вашего кода это time2
    # time2 уже строка
    if time2 == time:
        print("2")
        #os.system('shutdown /s /t 01')


ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(btn)

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(timeout)

#nums
time = ui.lineEdit.text()

#too nothing
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: У меня выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'QTimer' is not defined. Я разными способами пытался это импортировать

Comment: @Сергей его надо импортнуть `from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer`

Comment: Теперь у меня просто программа появляется на 1 секунду и вылетает

Comment: @Сергей немного изменил порядок кода. А что делает переменная `v` и откуда она?

Comment: Переменная v это текущее время

Comment: @Сергей где она объявлена? Это time2 наверное?

Comment: В ходе разработки я поменял имя переменной v на time2

Comment: @Сергей понял - в ответе я это учел ) И к строке приводить не надо, - time2 уже строка