Как обновлять label в определённое время?
Есть проблема с программой собранной на PyQt6.
Необходимо обновлять label каждый день в определённое время, нашёл, что есть способ через schedule, а именно:
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

Но когда я пробую добавить этот код к моей программе она не запускается, терминал намертво зависает и я даже не вижу графического окна приложения.
Узнал, что такие методы блокируют отрисовку интерфейса PyQt, но как мне тогда реализовать эту задумку?
Везде пишут про QTimer, но мне нужно ежедневно в определённое время.

Ну так добавьте QTimer с обработчиком schedule.run_pending. Да и стоит ли вообще дергать каждую секунду таймер там, где необходима(?) минутная точность?

P.S. модуль schedule удобен и его использование оправдано в тех случаях, когда на большое количество временных точек запланированы разные действия. В вашем случае это лишь избыточная зависимость. В обработчике таймера достаточно проверить текущее время и выполнить необходимые действия.

Milk, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Milk, отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143222 на ваш вопрос?
